# assistance with scraping json parse using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I successfully scraped the info of the json parse on this website, but I want to extract "all" of a specific data from the 'variants' array for example the 'inventory_quantity'. When I run my code it only shows the 1st array of the 'inventory_quantity' but I want it to extract all of the 'inventoryquantity' instead of just the 1st one.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.amongstfew.com/drops'


def scrape():
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    script = soup.find("script", class="draw_data_json").string.strip()
    data = json.loads(script)
    for i in data:
        print(i['title'], i['variants'][0]['inventory_quantity'])


scrape()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is list of dictionary so you can loop over it using `range` and `len` in python and also other inventory_quantity is inside variants you can loop over it and extract the information

code:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.amongstfew.com/drops'


def scrape():
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    script = soup.find("script", class="draw_data_json").string.strip()
    data = json.loads(script)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[i]['variants'])):
            print(data[i]['title'], data[i]['variants'][j]['inventory_quantity'])



scrape()
```

output:

```
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 1
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 1
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 1
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 1
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 1
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 1
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 1
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 2
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 2
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 1
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 1
adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM) 1
....
```

Comment: it works but how to make it scrape all instead of the 1st 5

Comment: So you dont want first five than start form the index 1 i have update my answer

Comment: oh i meant the entire inventory quantity not just the 1st 5 arrays of the inventory quantity

Comment: Okay i got your point we have iterate through variant correct now??

Answer (score 0):

The `variants` are just in a list. Iterate through those. Note when you iterate through a list there is no need for doing `range(1,len(data))`. You can simply slice the list with `list[1,:]`

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.amongstfew.com/drops'

def scrape():
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    script = soup.find("script", {'class':"draw_data_json"}).string.strip()
    data = json.loads(script)
    for i in data:
        print('%s\n%s\n%s' %('*'*60,i['title'].center(60, " "),'*'*60))
        for variant in i['variants']:
            print('\t %-30s %s' %(variant['title'], variant['inventory_quantity']))
        print('\n\n')

scrape()
```

**Output:**

```
************************************************************
         adidas - Yeezy 500 (ENFLAM/ENFLAM/ENFLAM)          
************************************************************
     US 5.5 / UK 5 / EU 38          1
     US 6 / UK 5.5 / EU 38 2/3      1
     US 6.5 / UK 6 / EU 39 1/3      1
     US 7 / UK 6.5 / EU 40          1
     US 7.5 / UK 7 / EU 40 2/3      1
     US 8 / UK 7.5 / EU 41 1/3      1
     US 8.5 / UK 8 / EU 42          1
     US 9 / UK 8.5 / EU 42 2/3      2
     US 9.5 / UK 9 / EU 43 1/3      2
     US 10 / UK 9.5 / EU 44         1
     US 10.5 / UK 10 / EU 44 2/3    1
     US 11 / UK 10.5 / EU 45 1/3    1
     US 11.5 / UK 11 / EU 46        1



************************************************************
     adidas - Yeezy BOOST 350 V2 (Sesame/Sesame/Sesame)     
************************************************************
     US 5 / UK 4.5 / EU 37 1/3      0
     US 5.5 / UK 5 / EU 38          0
     US 6 / UK 5.5 / EU 38 2/3      0
     US 6.5 / UK 6 / EU 39 1/3      0
     US 7 / UK 6.5 / EU 40          0
     US 7.5 / UK 7 / EU 40 2/3      0
     US 8 / UK 7.5 / EU 41 1/3      0
     US 8.5 / UK 8 / EU 42          0
     US 9 / UK 8.5 / EU 42 2/3      0
     US 9.5 / UK 9 / EU 43 1/3      0
     US 10 / UK 9.5 / EU 44         0
     US 10.5 / UK 10 / EU 44 2/3    0
     US 11 / UK 10.5 / EU 45 1/3    0
     US 11.5 / UK 11 / EU 46        0
     US 12 / UK 11.5 / EU 46 2/3    0
     US 12.5 / UK 12 / EU 47 1/3    0



************************************************************
  Air Jordan 1 High OG WMNS (Lucky Green/Black-White-Sail)  
************************************************************
     US 5 / UK 2.5 / EU 35.5        0
     US 5.5 / UK 3 / EU 36          0
     US 6 / UK 3.5 / EU 36.5        0
     US 6.5 / UK 4 / EU 37.5        0
     US 7 / UK 4.5 / EU 38          0
     US 7.5 / UK 5 / EU 38.5        0
     US 8 / UK 5.5 / EU 39          0
     US 8.5 / UK 6 / EU 40          0
     US 9 / UK 6.5 / EU 40.5        0
     US 9.5 / UK 7 / EU 41          0
     US 10 / UK 7.5 / EU 42         0
     US 10.5 / UK 8 / EU 42.5       0
     US 11 / UK 8.5 / EU 43         0
     US 11.5 / UK 9 / EU 44         0
     US 12 / UK 9.5 / EU 44.5       0



************************************************************
          Air Jordan 1 Low (Sail/White-LT Zitron)           
************************************************************
     US 7 / UK 6 / EU 40            0
     US 7.5 / UK 6.5 / EU 40.5      0
     US 8 / UK 7 / EU 41            0
     US 8.5 / UK 7.5 / EU 42        0
     US 9 / UK 8 / EU 42.5          1
     US 9.5 / UK 8.5 / EU 43        2
     US 10 / UK 9 / EU 44           0
     US 10.5 / UK 9.5 / EU 44.5     1
     US 11 / UK 10 / EU 45          1
     US 11.5 / UK 10.5 / EU 45.5    1
     US 12 / UK 11 / EU 46          0
     US 13 / UK 12 / EU 47.5        1



************************************************************
     Air Jordan 1 Zoom Air CMFT (Sail/White-LT Zitron)      
************************************************************
     US 7 / UK 6 / EU 40            1
     US 7.5 / UK 6.5 / EU 40.5      0
     US 8 / UK 7 / EU 41            1
     US 8.5 / UK 7.5 / EU 42        0
     US 9 / UK 8 / EU 42.5          0
     US 9.5 / UK 8.5 / EU 43        0
     US 10 / UK 9 / EU 44           0
     US 10.5 / UK 9.5 / EU 44.5     0
     US 11 / UK 10 / EU 45          0
     US 11.5 / UK 10.5 / EU 45.5    0
     US 12 / UK 11 / EU 46          1
     US 12.5 / UK 11.5 / EU 47      0
     US 13 / UK 12 / EU 47.5        1



************************************************************
  Air Jordan 11 Retro Low (White/Legend Blue-White-Black)   
************************************************************
     US 7 / UK 6 / EU 40            0
     US 7.5 / UK 6.5 / EU 40.5      1
     US 8 / UK 7 / EU 41            0
     US 8.5 / UK 7.5 / EU 42        0
     US 9 / UK 8 / EU 42.5          0
     US 9.5 / UK 8.5 / EU 43        0
     US 10 / UK 9 / EU 44           0
     US 10.5 / UK 9.5 / EU 44.5     0
     US 11 / UK 10 / EU 45          1
     US 11.5 / UK 10.5 / EU 45.5    0
     US 12 / UK 11 / EU 46          0
     US 12.5 / UK 11.5 / EU 47      0
     US 13 / UK 12 / EU 47.5        0
     US 14 / UK 13 / EU 48.5        0



************************************************************
     Air Jordan 4 X Union Retro SP (Off Noir/Red/Blue)      
************************************************************
     US 4 / UK 3.5 / EU 36          0
     US 4.5 / UK 4 / EU 36.5        0
     US 5 / UK 4.5 / EU 37.5        0
     US 5.5 / UK 5 / EU 38          0
     US 6 / UK 5.5 / EU 38.5        0
     US 6.5 / UK 6 / EU 39          0
     US 7 / UK 6 / EU 40            0
     US 7.5 / UK 6.5 / EU 40.5      0
     US 8 / UK 7 / EU 41            0
     US 8.5 / UK 7.5 / EU 42        0
     US 9 / UK 8 / EU 42.5          0
     US 9.5 / UK 8.5 / EU 43        0
     US 10 / UK 9 / EU 44           0
     US 10.5 / UK 9.5 / EU 44.5     0
     US 11 / UK 10 / EU 45          0
     US 11.5 / UK 10.5 / EU 45.5    0
     US 12 / UK 11 / EU 46          0
     US 12.5 / UK 11.5 / EU 47      0
     US 13 / UK 12 / EU 47.5        0
     US 14 / UK 13 / EU 48.5        0
     US 15 / UK 14 / EU 49.5        0



************************************************************
        Nike - Air Max 1 PRM (Pine Green/Pine Green)        
************************************************************
     US 5 / UK 4.5 / EU 37.5        0
     US 5.5 / UK 5 / EU 38          0
     US 6 / UK 5.5 / EU 38.5        0
     US 6.5 / UK 6 / EU 39          0
     US 7 / UK 6 / EU 40            0
     US 7.5 / UK 6.5 / EU 40.5      0
     US 8 / UK 7 / EU 41            0
     US 8.5 / UK 7.5 / EU 42        0
     US 9 / UK 8 / EU 42.5          0
     US 9.5 / UK 8.5 / EU 43        0
     US 10 / UK 9 / EU 44           0
     US 10.5 / UK 9.5 / EU 44.5     0
     US 11 / UK 10 / EU 45          0
     US 11.5 / UK 10.5 / EU 45.5    0
     US 12 / UK 11 / EU 46          0



************************************************************
     Nike - WMNS Dunk Low (Lemon Drop/Opti Yellow-Sail)     
************************************************************
     US 5.5 / UK 3 / EU 36          1
     US 6 / UK 3.5 / EU 36.5        1
     US 6.5 / UK 4 / EU 37.5        1
     US 7 / UK 4.5 / EU 38          1
     US 7.5 / UK 5 / EU 38.5        1
     US 8 / UK 5.5 / EU 39          1
     US 8.5 / UK 6 / EU 40          1
     US 9 / UK 6.5 / EU 40.5        1
     US 9.5 / UK 7 / EU 41          1
     US 10 / UK 7.5 / EU 42         1
     US 10.5 / UK 8 / EU 42.5       1
     US 11 / UK 8.5 / EU 43         1
     US 11.5 / UK 9 / EU 44         1
     US 12 / UK 9.5 / EU 44.5       1
```